# How to get OpenCV to detect python installed with conda in docker

Tags: python, opencv, docker, conda

I have composed a docker file from a few sources, but keep running into the problem that when building opencv, it will not find python.

I added the dockerfile to https://gist.github.com/pksorensen/e06a783c31d4e95e60f1376baa8d562e as the post start to hit limit.

The problem shows at the end when cv2 is not avaible from python

```
chainer@cbd2c9c51a21:/src/image-labelling-tool/examples/ssd$ python
Python 3.5.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:53:06)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'cv2'
>>>
```

I come to the conclusion that its due to the use of conda and opencv from two docker files and I am guessing :) Much appreciated if anyone can share some light on what i am doing wrong?

Output from cmake step is here https://gist.github.com/pksorensen/e06a783c31d4e95e60f1376baa8d562e#file-out-txt

Comment: It looks like you installed `opencv` while `conda` wasn't installed yet. The output of `cmake` showed that it installed on `python 3.4.3`. You then installed `conda` which is `3.5.2` and you expect `opencv` to be in there. Try running `/usr/bin/python3.4` and see if you can `import cv2` from there.

Comment: woops. ye, i will reorder it and try again

Comment: i updated the docker file with opencv last, but it gives the same result. python not working

Comment: It looks like `which python3` is picking up `/usr/bin/python3`. Try replacing this `-D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=$(which python3)` with `-D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=$CONDA_DIR/bin/python3`. Then post the output of `cmake`.

Comment: I updated it and added links to the output and dockerfile

Answer (score 1):

using PYTHON3 variables solved it.

```
-D PYTHON3_LIBRARY=$CONDA_DIR/lib/python3.5 \
-D PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIRS=$CONDA_DIR/include/python3.5m \
-D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=$CONDA_DIR/bin/python3 \
-D PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH=$CONDA_DIR/lib/python3.5/site-packages \

--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 /opt/conda/bin/python3 (ver 3.6.2)
--     Libraries:                   /opt/conda/lib/python3.5 (ver 3.6.2)
--     numpy:                       /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.13.1)
--     packages path:               /opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```